# Code Coverage Screen hangs in Azure Pipeline Build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cobertura

Im currently setting up an azure pipeline for my repository. Currently it builds correctly and runs the unit tests. However the code coverage tab just spins infinitely. Any idea on what would cause this?

**Details**:

The artifact directory looks like this:

[image]

The console shows this error:

> Error: Could not find route for route id
>   ms.vss-tfs-web.project-overview-route. Ensure that the requested route
>   is added to routes shared data.

This is how the test results are ran and generated:

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --tool-path .

dotnet test $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\RulesMadeEasy.Tests -c debug --logger trx --no-restore /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura --results-directory $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\ /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\

.\reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\ -reporttypes:"HTMLInline_AzurePipelines;Badges" --version 4.0.0-rc4
```

The code coverage results are published using the PublishCodeCoverageResults@1 task with the following inputs
    inputs:
        codeCoverageTool: Cobertura

```
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\coverage.cobertura.xml'

    reportDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults'
```

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/385331/code-coverage-results-not-rendered-in-build-result.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable the *Boards* service in you Azure DevOps project to let the error disappear.

Comment: we have a winner